# Catalina Mail super slow when composing new emails?

Tags: mail.app, catalina, performance

More people experience slow emails on Catalina?

Running a MacPro with `64 Gb` RAM and its slow like fek. **Especially when typing emails feels very laggy**.

Running latest version `10.15.2` and I have the `check spell why you type` is off. Got 8 mailboxes of which one is a `Office 360`. Under settings `iCloud`, I switched off mail (FWIW). Plenty of diskspace (> 1.4 TB free).

I also tried a reboot and PRAM reset.

Anybody got a clue?

Comment: What does Activity Monitor look like? Which Mac Pro... a 2013 or older with an unofficial Catalina upgrade?

Comment: Check Activity monitor to see if any process misbehaves when you make a new draft. Also, try to single out the account by manually filling out the "send using" field and keeping the rest of the accounts offline.

Comment: @Tetsujin Cylinder model, it *is* an official upgrade. I checked the activity nothing special there, other then sometimes its running ~ 115% CPU. I'm not sure if its more often when replying or new (now I think of it). Its for sure not consistent, and by times *extremely* slow (like a letter per second).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up a Finder app session
2. You will need access to your User library
3. Go to Folder `Containers > com.apple.mail > Data > Library > Saved Application State`
   [image]
   `Go > Go To Folder` and type in as shown above.
4. Move com.apple.mail.savedState to Trash
   [image]
   Move this folder to the trash
5. Next, in Finder app, press down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and click on Go at the top of the menu
6. Type in `~/Library/Containers`
7. Drag `com.apple.mail` and `com.apple.MailServiceAgent` out to your desktop
8. Similarly, remove the envelope files from `~/Library/Mail/MailData` and drag them to trash

   - Envelope Index
   - Envelope Index-shm
   - Envelope Index-wal
9. Empty your Trash and Restart your Mac

If your Mail works without hiccups, you can move the files from your desktop into Trash ( file from step 8 above).

Comment: Thanks, I only have ~/Library/Mail/V7/MailData (already did remove state and reboot no dice). Maildata is > 3 GB what's stored there? Will try the *Containers* trick.